# why local variable doesn't hide the global variable in array definition

Tags: c++

I am reviewing subtle points in C++ these days. I found an interesting question. Could you please check it and share your reasoning why it works like that.

Thank you

```
const int x = 5;

void func() {
    // ! Error    
    // int x = x;

    // ! Fine    
    int x[x];
    x[0] = 12;
    cout << x[0];
}
```

Comment: What makes you sure it's not hiding `const int x = 5;` ?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ i didn't understand your question but i guess you are asking that why array definition is working right ? if it is that, i already compiled and checked it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The point of declaration for a variable (that is, the point at which the name assumes the meaning given to it by the declaration, hiding any other entities with the same name in a wider scope) comes after the declarator, and before any initialiser. So this:

```
int x = x;
     ^ point of declaration
```

initialises the local variable `x` with its own uninitialised value, giving undefined behaviour (although it's still well-formed, so the compiler shouldn't reject it unless you ask it to).

While this:

```
int x[x];
        ^ point of declaration
```

uses the global constant `x` within the declarator, which is well-formed and well-defined. It's potentially baffling for human readers, but no problem for the compiler.

The rationale for this rule is that it's reasonable to use the address (but not the value) of a variable in its own initialiser, a simple example being

```
void * p = &p;
```

Comment: @MuratKarakuş: It uses the address of the variable (which is well-defined before initialisation), not the value (which is undefined).

Comment: Thanks @Mike, I got it now